# Error when load form data in W2UI. "Cannot associate field "id" with html control"

Tags: w2ui

My form can not update data which it got from server to form's record.
Below is my w2form

```
$().w2form({
                    name: 'editSv',
                    method: 'GET',
                    style: 'border: 0px; background-color: transparent;',
                    recid: w2ui['grid'].records[w2ui['grid'].getSelection(true)]['id'],
                    url: {
                        get: '/api/Test/GetService/' + w2ui['grid'].records[w2ui['grid'].getSelection(true)]['id'],
                        save: '/api/Test/PostService'
                    },
                    formURL: '/api/Test/GetService/' + w2ui['grid'].records[w2ui['grid'].getSelection(true)]['id'],
                    fields: [
                        { name: 'id', type: 'number', required: true },
                        { name: 'servicename', type: 'text', required: true },
                        { name: 'price', type: 'number', required: true },
                        { name: 'unit', type: 'text' }
                    ],
                    record: {
                        id: 0,
                        servicename: '',
                        price: 0,
                        unit: ''
                    }, onSubmit: function (formName, formObj) {
                        formObj.postData = formObj.postData.record;
                    },
                    onLoad: function (event) {
                        console.log(event.xhr);
                    },
                    actions: {
                        "save": function () {
                            var obj = this;
                            this.submit({}, function (data) {
                                if (data.status == 'success') {
                                    w2alert(data.status);
                                    w2ui['grid'].reload();
                                } else {
                                    w2alert(data.message);
                                    return;
                                }
                                obj.clear();
                            });
                        },
                        "reset": function () { this.clear(); },
                    }
                });
```

This is data got from onLoad() event

```
{readyState: 4, responseText: "{"id":5,"servicename":"4","price":4.0000,"unit":"4"}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

And the message from chrome's console:

```
ERROR: Cannot associate field "id" with html control. Make sure html control exists with the same name.
ERROR: Cannot associate field "servicename" with html control. Make sure html control exists with the same name.
ERROR: Cannot associate field "price" with html control. Make sure html control exists with the same name.
ERROR: Cannot associate field "unit" with html control. Make sure html control exists with the same name.
```

I have tried to add formHTML to w2form but it makes no sense. Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: `formHTML` is ignored if `formURL` is set (like in your example). You need to make sure your `formURL` data contains the required input fields with the appropritate `name` attributes. If using [Auto-Templates](http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!forms/forms-10) solves the issue, the problem is definitely with your formUrl.

Comment: Work like a charm. Please add answers.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
Have you defined any HTML page for your w2ui form in this case you can use kickstart or you can define formHTML in your form:


$().w2form({
            name: 'editSv',
            style:'border: 0px',
            focus:-1,method: 'GET',
                        style: 'border: 0px; background-color: transparent;',
                        recid: w2ui['grid'].records[w2ui['grid'].getSelection(true)]['id'],
                        url: {
                            get: '/api/Test/GetService/' + w2ui['grid'].records[w2ui['grid'].getSelection(true)]['id'],
                            save: '/api/Test/PostService'
                        },
                        formURL: '/api/Test/GetService/' + w2ui['grid'].records[w2ui['grid'].getSelection(true)]['id'],
            formHTML: 
                '<div class="w2ui-page page-0">'+
                '    <div class="w2ui-field">'+
                '        <label> id </label>'+
                '        <div>'+
                '            <input name="id" type="text" />'+
                '        </div>'+
                '    </div>'+            '    <div class="w2ui-field">'+
                '        <label> id </label>'+
                '        <div>'+
                '            <input name="id" type="text" />'+
                '        </div>'+
                '    </div>'+            '    <div class="w2ui-field">'+
                '        <label> price </label>'+
                '        <div>'+
                '            <input name="price" type="text" />'+
                '        </div>'+
                '    </div>'+            '    <div class="w2ui-field">'+
                '        <label> unit </label>'+
                '        <div>'+
                '            <input name="unit" type="text" />'+
                '        </div>'+
                '    </div>'+
                '<div class="w2ui-buttons">'+
                '   <button class="btn" name="Cancel">Cancel</button>'+
                '    <button class="btn" name="Save">Save</button>'+
                '</div>',
    fields: [
                            { name: 'id', type: 'number', required: true },
                            { name: 'servicename', type: 'text', required: true },
                            { name: 'price', type: 'number', required: true },
                            { name: 'unit', type: 'text' }
                        ],
                        record: {
                            id: 0,
                            servicename: '',
                            price: 0,
                            unit: ''
                        }, onSubmit: function (formName, formObj) {
                            formObj.postData = formObj.postData.record;
                        },
                        onLoad: function (event) {
                            console.log(event.xhr);
                        },
                        actions: {
                            "save": function () {
                                var obj = this;
                                this.submit({}, function (data) {
                                    if (data.status == 'success') {
                                        w2alert(data.status);
                                        w2ui['grid'].reload();
                                    } else {
                                        w2alert(data.message);
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    obj.clear();
                                });
                            },
                            "reset": function () { this.clear(); },
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: comment from @mpf82 is right, you too. I need to define html page before using option formurl.